# Dynamically importing of components - Got error "React.createElement: type is invalid"

Tags: reactjs, import

I'm having trouble with dynamically importing components in my code. The error message is:

> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string
> (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
> components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your
> component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up
> default and named imports.

I know that there are a lot of the same errors to find in the web and I already read, that it could be an issue of how I importing the namespace, but actually I did not get it to work.
Maybe someone could give a hint or a solution to my problem:

The situation:
Depending on the `navigation` property I want to import the suitable component view. So the value of `this.props.navigation` is a string value, which possible value is i.e. `SignInView`. When you open the page first time the value is `null`.

This is the code of my `App.js` file:

```
import React, { Component, lazy, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import NavBarComponent from './components/navbar.component';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { updateNavigation, updateUser, updateLanguage } from './actions/index';

const importView = async view => {
    if(view === undefined || view === null) {
        view = "Null";
    }
    return lazy(() =>
        import(`./views/${String(view).toLowerCase()}View`)
        .catch(() =>
            import(`./views/nullView`)
        ))
};

class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        };
    }
    
    render() {
        const View = importView(this.props.navigation);
        return (
            <div>
                <NavBarComponent
                    key={"navBarComponent"}
                />
                {this.props.navigation}
                <React.Suspense fallback='Loading view...'>
                    <View key={"view"} />
                </React.Suspense>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps({ user, navigation, language}) {
    return {
        user,
        navigation,
        language,
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        updateUser: user => dispatch(updateUser(user)),
        updateNavigation: navigation => dispatch(updateNavigation(navigation)),
        updateLanguage: language => dispatch(updateLanguage(language)),
    };
}
 
const Form = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(App);
 
export default Form;
```

As you can see in the `render()` method, I want to import the view with this line:

```
const View = importView(this.props.navigation);
```

Here are two examples of components (views), which I want to import:

**signinView.js:**

```
import React from 'react';

export const SignInView = () => {
    return (
        <div>Sign In View </div>
    );
}

export default SignInView;
```

**nullView.js:**

```
import React from 'react';

const NullView = () => {
    return (
        <div>No View found</div>
    );
}

export default NullView;
```

Could it be an issue of upper / lowercase letters?

Comment: Any reason you using dynamic import? That's obviously not a use case for it.

Comment: I just found the code so much cleaner than using a big switch case. So is it not possible or not recommended?

Comment: And the error might come from another source: `{this.props.navigation}`

Comment: Why would you use switch case? You have conditional rendering, mapping from object and many more

Comment: No, the value of `this.props.navigation` is as I wrote `null` in the beginning, then after navigating i.e. `SignInView` or something different, but a string value

Comment: Try replicate the behavior: https://codesandbox.io/s/vanilla-react-template-irhcq, you don't need redux to replicate the error, I'll try to show an alternative solution because I never seen lazy used like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one of many alternatives solutions, if you notice, the components in `VIEWS` object are not initialized, and they will only render on JSX invoke:

```
import NullView from '...';
import StringView from '...';

const VIEWS = {
  stringView: StringView,
  nullView: NullView,
};

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const View = VIEWS[this.props.navigation];
    return (
      <>
        <NavBarComponent />
        {this.props.navigation}
        <View  />
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok. That's as you wrote a workaround. But a suitable... ;-)

Comment: Thank you! Your answer helped me a lot!